# File not found with Python's fileinput

Tags: python, file-io

Given the following code:

```
# Edit build number in test report
print(path)  # TODO remove
html_report = fileinput.input(path, inplace=True)
for line in html_report:
    print(line.replace('$BUILD_NUMBER',
                       args.number).rstrip())
html_report.close()
```

I get the following output:

```
/home/jenkins/workspace/reports/report201610261053.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "report_generator.py", line 58, in <module>
    for line in html_report:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/fileinput.py", line 252, in next
    line = self.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/fileinput.py", line 321, in readline
    os.rename(self._filename, self._backupfilename)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

If I just use the command:

```
gedit /home/jenkins/workspace/reports/report201610261053.html
```

I can check that the file exists. In fact, if it didn't I would expect this error to be raised in the `fileinput.input()` line, not in the line loop.

Any idea of what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What is your "path" value?
I think you should try to use absolute path

You can also check the user permissions to file.

Comment: I have shown the output when path is printed: it is an absolute path. Permissions are -rw-r--r--, which I guess it is enough for reading and editing it with this user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong in the code that you have shown.

> I can check that the file exists. In fact, if it didn't I would expect
>   this error to be raised in the fileinput.input() line, not in the line
>   loop.

The error is reported only when an attempt is made to open file and it happens in the for loop.

Is it possible that your code is running under a different user and doesn't see the file on that path as compared to you manually verifying file existence?

Comment: The user is the same, but using open between try/except, I have found something strange: File is not found either, and the exception says: No such file or directory: '/home/jenkins/workspace/reports/report201610261336.html\x1b'. Where did that '\x1b' came from? If I just print path variable before the open function it gets printed once again correctly, without the '\x1b'.